# Store SlashCommandBuilder options in another js file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have an option in a SlashCommandBuilder that goes like this:

```
.addStringOption((option) => option
    .setName('city')
    .setDescription('In which city are you currently based from?')
    .addChoices(
        { 
           name: 'City 1', 
           value: 'City-1-Example' 
        }, 
        { 
           name: 'City 2', 
           value: 'City-2-Example' 
        }
    )
    .setRequired(true)
)
```

I was thinking of creating another separate `.js` file, let's say `options.js` that contains:

```
export const options = {
    city: [
        { 
           name: 'City 1', 
           value: 'City-1-Example' 
        }, 
        { 
           name: 'City 2', 
           value: 'City-2-Example' 
        }
    ],

    optionsForAnotherCommand: [
        ...
    ]
}
```

so that I could easily edit options in one file for all SlashCommandBuilder options. Makes it organized and clean, I can go ahead and do this now:

```
.addStringOption((option) => option
    .setName('city')
    .setDescription('In which city are you currently based from?')
    .addChoices(options.city)
    .setRequired(true)
)
```

However, it returns to me an error:

```
errors: [[ 0, ValidationError: Expected the value to not be an array ...
```

The code works with the first example, but it's going to be a hassle if I want to change options for all of my commands since I have to open them file by file. Was wondering if this is possible or if it's not, is there a more organized way to store your options in a SlashCommandBuilder?

Comment: You can see that the first one is not an array. You should use the spread operator: `.addChoices(...options.city)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer @Zsolt Meszaros.

The answer is simple, you just add `...` before it:

```
.addChoices(...options.city)
```